# Get the selected item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menu

Sorry if my question is too simple, but I can't figure it out from the jQuery UI documentation.

How can I determine which option was clicked within a menu? I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
var menu = $('#menu');
menu.menu({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.type);
    }
});​
```

Comment: You're looking for the text value of the menu item you click on?

Comment: I think so. I need an action to the click, and it changes depending on the option selected.

Comment: @ExplosionPills http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Comment: .menu is here: http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are missing is the fact that 'ui' is a jQuery object that represents the item you clicked.

so to get the text out of that item you should be using:

```
    var menu = $('#menu');

    $(document).ready(function(){
        menu.menu({
            select: function(event, ui) {
                alert(ui.item.text());
            }
        });
    });
```

That will give you the text of the item.

[here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bY7d/1/)

Comment: I am glad. Your welcome. The API Documentation can be a bit confusing.

Comment: With nested menus this gives too much text as result :/

Comment: Had to use ui.item[0].childNodes[1].data to get just current node text

Comment: Not sure how nested they have to be before this stops working. [Here is an example with nested menus](http://jsfiddle.net/02txmbm4/15/)